# Why executor service submitted task is not executing the task async?

Tags: java, future, executorservice, completable-future, java.util.concurrent

I'm trying to play with async java in my intellij local. My intention is that i will call `calucalateAsync()` method from main method and then put the debug point on `System.out.println("calculate async was called");`.

Ideally the submitted task to executors service should be executed concurrently, but the issue is until the execution of the main method is being done, the task is never being executed. Please let me know

Please find below the code:

CompletableFuturePlay.java

```
public class CompletableFuturePlay {

public void calculateAsync() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("inside calculate async method");
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10).submit(() -> {
        System.out.println("inside the submitted task");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("completed the thread");
        return;
    });
    
    System.out.println("outside executores block");
    
}}
```

PlayGround.java

```
public class PlayGround {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    CompletableFuturePlay completableFuturePlay = new CompletableFuturePlay();
    completableFuturePlay.calculateAsync();
    System.out.println("calculate async was called");
}}
```

Output I'm seeing in terminal:
[image]

Comment: "*... but the issue is until the execution of the main method is being done, the task is never being executed.*" - How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @Turing85 until i play the breakpoint on sout in main method, the submitted code was not being executed. I waited for more than 10 mins and tried multiple times

Comment: unable to reproduce - with posted code, I get 4 lines of output, last one being "completed the thread" when stopping at the line of "calculate async was called" (but I am using Eclipse) What exactly is the output you are seeing?

Comment: A debugger may limit parallel execution to aid debugging. We see this regularly in web applications. If we hit an endpoint to trigger a breakpoint and then (while the debugger stays at the breakpoint) hit the endpoint or even any other endpoint, the browser keeps loading.

Comment: @user85421 added output in the question. Can u share any screenshot?

Comment: @Turing85 then how can i debug this scenario? The only option I could see is adding sleep in main method, this is working as expected. But is this the only way we can test?

Comment: so you don't believe me :-/ - here you got it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2nzO.png

Comment: @user85421 but how could this happen? any idea?

Comment: @vinter concerning "how can I debug this scenario?", I suggest you have a look at the class CountDownLatch.

Comment: First, there are some issues with the code. Most notable, the `ExecutorService` is never closed. Second, what exactly do you want to test? The code is executed asynchronously, on another thread. We can make this visible by adding some output with the thread's name (`Thread.currentThread().getName()`).

Comment: @Turing85 i know that the code is getting executed in async, but i was thinking if i put debug point in main method, ideally even without explicit Thread.sleep() in main method, the task should get executed in parallel thread

Comment: It gets executed on another thread. You even verified this yourself by adding a `Thread.sleep()`. Could it be that you confuse parallelism with synchronization?

Comment: _but i was thinking if i put debug point in main method, ideally even without explicit Thread.sleep() in main method, the task should get executed in parallel thread_: it depends. When you set the breakpoint, you have the option to stop only the current thread, or all threads (I don't know the parallelism in Eclipse, but in IntelliJ is by default "all threads" and you can choose to stop only the current thread). If you're blocking all threads, you may see the async task start (it depends on who gets there first), but you'll never see it ending because of Thread.sleep.

Comment: I really suggest you to have a look at the CountDownLatch. You pass the latch to the async method and you countDown() from the async thread. On the main thread, you wait on the latch. Like that, you are 100% sure you're waiting no more nor less than what's needed for the async thread to complete.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ thanks for the suggestions. By default breakpoint is suspending all the current threads and yes, after changing it to suspend only the current thread, it executed the job concurrently.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ please post the upvoted comments in the answer so i can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakpoints can suspend:

- All threads
- Just the current thread

By default, in IntelliJ Idea, a breakpoint will suspend all threads.

If you launch `main` (that will run `calculateAsync` on a separate thread) and you set a breakpoint on the line coming just after the call to `calculateAsync` that suspends all threads, what will happen is:

1. Randomly, the beginning of `calculateAsync` may appear before you hit the breakpoint. However, this is not very likely (the thread has to fork, which takes "some time", so it's more likely that you hit the main breakpoint before the thread actually has the time to start.
2. The main breakpoint is hit, so all threads will stop (here including the async thread that is running `calculateAsync`)
3. Hence, because of the `Thread.sleep` within the second thread, you will never see the end of it until when the breakpoint is not released.

The "easiest" option to observe the wished behavior is to set the breakpoint to *suspend current thread* only. If you do that, the secondary thread will be free to run even after you hit your breakpoint and so you will see what you wish to see.

However, this is not a solid way to setup a multi-threading test. My suggestion is to use a `CountDownLatch` as follows (p.s. I'm writing the code directly on StackOverflow so I may be doing some mistake, please use some tolerance when actually running it):

```
public class CompletableFuturePlay {

public void calculateAsync(CountDownLatch latch, ExecutorService executor) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Scheduling asynchronous execution");
    executor.submit(() -> {
        System.out.println("Asynchrounous execution started");
        // do whatever consuming job here. You can mock it with a Thread.sleep if you want
        System.out.println("Asynchronous execution ended");
        latch.countDown(); //send a signal to the latch that your job is over
        return;
    });
    
    System.out.println("Scheduled asynchronous execution");
    
}}
```

... and then the usage:

```
public class PlayGround {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1); //<-- only 1 is enough
    CompletableFuturePlay completableFuturePlay = new CompletableFuturePlay();
    completableFuturePlay.calculateAsync(latch, executor);
    System.out.println("calculate async was called");
    latch.await(1, Time.MINUTES); //<-- ask the main thread to wait for the other thread to complete the execution - timeout after 1 minute
    System.out.println("resume execution of main thread");
}}
```